# SQLAlchemy query_expression values lost after performing union query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've reduced my issue down to the simplest reproducible example I could.

You can run a Replit version of the script below interactively here: https://replit.com/@jackevansevo/LightblueDarkgreenSystems#main.py

Ideally I'd expect the output of this script to be:

```
True
False
[True, False]
```

However, my script is printing

```
True
False,
[None, None]
```

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import literal
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy import union_all
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import query_expression
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import with_expression



Base = declarative_base()


class Tweet(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tweet"
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = Column(String)
    liked = query_expression()


engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


with Session(engine) as session:

    tweet_a = Tweet(content="A")
    tweet_b = Tweet(content="B")

    session.add_all([tweet_a, tweet_b])

    session.commit()

# Commenting out this line fixes the query...
with Session(engine) as session:
    query_a = (
        select(Tweet)
        .options(with_expression(Tweet.liked, literal(True)))
        .where(Tweet.id == 1)
    )

    print(session.scalars(query_a).first().liked)

    query_b = (
        select(Tweet)
        .options(with_expression(Tweet.liked, literal(False)))
        .where(Tweet.id == 2)
    )

    print(session.scalars(query_b).first().liked)

    union_query = select(Tweet).from_statement(union_all(query_a, query_b))

    print([t.liked for t in session.scalars(union_query).all()])
```

The first query here prints `True` (as I'd expect)

```py
    query_a = (
        select(Tweet)
        .options(with_expression(Tweet.liked, literal(True)))
        .where(Tweet.id == 1)
    )

    print(session.scalars(query_a).first().liked)
```

The second query here prints `False` (as I'd expect)

```py
    query_b = (
        select(Tweet)
        .options(with_expression(Tweet.liked, literal(False)))
        .where(Tweet.id == 2)
    )

    print(session.scalars(query_b).first().liked)
```

However, when I perform a Union of the two queries, I end up with `[None, None]`

```py
    union_query = select(Tweet).from_statement(union_all(query_a, query_b))

    print([t.liked for t in session.scalars(union_query).all()])
```

Is there anyway to preserve the value of `Tweet.liked` after the two queries have been joined?

Observation: What's intriguing is that the final union query appears to succeed if I run it as part of the same session (as where I create the data), but only if the original two queries have already been executed.

I have a feeling this is something to do with the way sessions in SQLAlchemy behave, but I can't root out the error in my program.

Comment: The [doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.with_expression) for `with_expression` suggests that you need to call `populate_existing()` to fix this, but it only seems to available on `session.query`, not `select`. (This should be fine, as `session.query` isn't going away any time soon, but perhaps aesthetically displeasing).